# Regarding MVC3 master page and user control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

**Regarding MVC3 MASTER PAGE ISSUE**
I have  one master page and inside that master page i have used one usercontrol.
Now inside that usercontrol I have bind out one dropdown list from database from actionresult.

Now the problem is that whenever I use another view i have to call that action result for binding that dropdown list again and again in all other pages which include my master page.
How could I prevent this from happening?
Remember my friends, I am using MVC3.

Comment: Please include code examples of your views and Actions to help clarify the question.

Comment: hey..simply understand like that in master page i have one dropdown control..now I dont want to bind that dropdown control in all action results which uses that master page..how could i prevent that..??

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, I understand that you want do not want to make DB call on your execution of each view as you included Dropdown in masterpage.

To overcome this problem, you need to implement ouputcache for that usercontrol (partialpage). Please find more details [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs). Do let me know if you still have any query.

Comment: Ya I have currently done caching technique for preventing route to database..but the problem is that..this is not the proper method..there must be someway out..to prevent from DB call....on all action results..

Comment: This is the proper method? Another possibility is that you cache the data from the database on the server so that instead of going to the database to build the drop down, you use the cached data. But this will likely require some form of synchronization from you. Using output cache might just be the appropriate thing for you.

Comment: @darshandoshi .. this is a best thing you can do to reduce a DB call. PLease mark as an answer if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to check data from DB then make a static dictionary and bind it to the DropDownListFor:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<int, string> yourData
    = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { "1", "Your data one" },
    { "2", "Your data two" }
};
```

Regards

Comment: ya but dropdown value can change..since my requirement is from database

Comment: How often does the data change, as you said you don't want to get it on every actionresult?